# JQuery datepicker pre define dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery date picker and i wanted to highlight several dates that are pre-define dates.I saw several answers while googling,but not success

My code:

```
var availableDates = ["30-1-2016", "15-1-2016", "16-1-2016"];

$('#Datepicker').datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: availableDates 
});
```

But it doesn't show the 'available dates'( Actually i wanted to highlight available dates in the jquery calendar )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the below JS

```
var datesToBeHighlighted=['1/1/2016','1/5/2016'];

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
         inline: true,
         beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var theday = (date.getMonth()+1) +'/'+ date.getDate()+ '/' + date.getFullYear();
            return [true,$.inArray(theday, datesToBeHighlighted) >=0?"hightlight":''];
                        }
});
```

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lokcre03/